# Refreshing RecyclerView in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

In my fragment I have a `refresh()` method which loads RecyclerView in particular fragment after fetching data from server using `AsyncDataClass extends AsyncTask`. and in my RecycleView Adapter I am using `ContextMenu` from which I am calling test function of fragment responsible for executing another `AsyncDeleteClass extends AsyncTask` which deletes the particular item from the remote server database.
My problem is that I am calling `refresh()` method in `PostExecute` method of `AsyncDeleteClass` as it gets delete confirmation.But my `RecyclerView` is not refreshing even if the particular item is deleted.

**OnCreateView and ReshDisplay() :**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /* Allow activity to show indeterminate progress-bar */

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_plcaes_card_list,container,false);
       ctx=inflater.getContext();

    //Get Calling Activity an call its function
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    user_id = activity.getUserId();
   // Toast.makeText(activity,user_id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    RefreshDisplay();
    return view;
}

private void RefreshDisplay(){
    recList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardList);
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(ctx);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recList.setLayoutManager(llm);
    AsyncDataClass asyncRequestObject = new AsyncDataClass();
    asyncRequestObject.execute(serverurl);
}
```

**test() method Responsible for deleting and refreshing RecyclerView**

```
public void test(String dpid){
    deletePid = dpid;
    AsyncDeleteClass asyncDeleteRequestObject = new AsyncDeleteClass();
    asyncDeleteRequestObject.execute(deleteServerUrl);
}
```

**AsyncDeleteClass:**

```
private class AsyncDeleteClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String responseBody = "";

            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            String jsonResult = "";
            try {

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
                System.out.println("Returned Json object " + jsonResult.toString());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jsonResult;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.i("Async : ","PRe Exec");
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
            if(result.equals("") || result == null){
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Server connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            int jsonResult = returnParsedJsonObject(result);
            if(jsonResult == -1){
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Sorry Unable To Delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            if(jsonResult == 1){

                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Place Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                RefreshDisplay();
            }
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return answer;
        }
    }
```

**AsyncDataClass:**

```
    private class AsyncDataClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String responseBody = "";

            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            String jsonResult = "";
            try {

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
                System.out.println("Returned Json object " + jsonResult.toString());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jsonResult;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.i("Async : ","PRe Exec");
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
            if(result.equals("") || result == null){
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Server connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            int jsonResult = returnParsedJsonObject(result);
            if(jsonResult == -1){
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Sorry No Places Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            if(jsonResult == 1){
                //Toast.makeText(ctx, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    places = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < places.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject place = places.getJSONObject(i);
//                        String slot = c.getString(TAG_SLOT);
//                        serverReturn.add(slot);
                          UserPlaces placeFroServer = new UserPlaces();
                          placeFroServer.setId(place.getString(TAG_PID));
                          placeFroServer.setName(place.getString(TAG_PNAME));
                          placeFroServer.setDescription(place.getString(TAG_DESC));
                          placeFroServer.setImg(place.getString(TAG_IMG));
                          placeFroServer.setLat(place.getString(TAG_LAT));
                          placeFroServer.setLng(place.getString(TAG_LNG));
                          placesList.add(placeFroServer);

                    }

                    places_adapter = new PlacersCardAdapter(placesList,ctx, CheckPlacesFragment.this);
                    recList.setAdapter(places_adapter);


                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    String ex = e.getMessage();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return answer;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are not setting the adapter in `onPostExecute` as you do in `AsyncDataClass`

Comment: @user1779222 but my refresh() is calling executing `AsyncDataClass` in return which is called in `onPostExecute()` of `AsyncDeleteClass`.